# How can you get the "var svgData" out of an image?

Tags: string, image, svg, base64, var

Ive been trying to figure out how to code a image into a "var svgData" code for quite some time, yet i only found one similar question in the internet with no helpful solution. There is a webisite called "gtalogo" (http://gtalogo.com/), where you can basically look for emblems you want to apply to your gta crew.

But in order to upload a image on the website, you need a "var svgData='(Code)=';var layerData='(another Code)='" first, and I have no idea how you can get that code out of a svg file, png file, jpg file, or whatever.
Ive tried to convert svg to base64, but that didnt solve the problem because there is still the "var layerData".

I can give you a example of one image which is on the gtalogo webiste, and got coded into "var svgData".
image: https://en.gtalogo.com/img/16479.webp
code: (too long), but you can see it on this link, when you click on "show code": [https://en.gtalogo.com/emblem-16479.html"](https://en.gtalogo.com/emblem-16479.html%22). This is a random emblem btw.

And my task is to get the "var svgData" code, which you saw on the website, out of my image. This is the image: [My image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VqRX.png)

(no questions asked (im not a communist)).

And this is the svg: https://mega.nz/file/HGJlCIQS#iOlt6jdVDGJV98Ay_HpnHudtB94rncehgCnKQgq39GY

Base64 code if you need it: https://mega.nz/file/yGRFjQCK#uslnTQe5kqxqE1RJABXnGeBkmxZ19fVPQeiPjg253ks

So, if someone knows what im talking about and is able to describe me how i can get the var svgData code, or is able to code it for me, it would be very appreciated.

TrileX_

Answer (score 0):

`svgData` is not tied to the image itself. It's a value that Rockstar services create for each of the emblems that are successfully created.
[EDIT: While `svgData` is actually tied to the image and can be easily reproduced, but you still need `layerData` which is from Rockstar editor]

To upload an image to "gtalogo" you need to use a command in console (`copy(_sc_av_edit+'|||'+document.getElementById("emblemEditor-canvasContainer").innerHTML)`). First part is the code generated by Rockstar and the second part is the vector image itself.
While the second part you can get without any issues, the first part you can only get from an already saved emblem (as far as I know).

In conclusion, you either have to use a pre-existing emblem or make one yourself in the Rockstar emblem editor.

Comment: I'm gonna go more in depth about what is `svgData` and `layerData` in this comment.

`svgData` is just the `<svg>` object encoded in Base64.

`layerData` is a list of Rockstar's emblem editor layers encoded in Base64. Each layer has these attributes: [id, name, type, y, x, scaleY, scaleX, invertedY, invertedX, rotation, opacity, index, color, isFilled, internal, locked, tBold, tItalic, fontFamily, borderColor, borderSize, gradientStyle, slug, width, height]

There is no way that I know of, that you can import your own vector image to Rockstar's format